# How would you answer when tasked with the estimation of a person's intelligence?

Tags: language, intelligence

> "She is so intelligent, right?"

Well, to agree with such a statement, we would need to have a mutual understanding of intelligence, which we probably don't, since there are many different definitions of intelligence and I assume most people in fact have their own. Secondly such a definition of intelligence would require it to be quantifiable and comparable, if we assume that the statement above implies the meaning that she is more intelligent than an average person. Most definitions of intelligence are vague in the sense that they don't specifically state the quantifiability of intelligence. Thirdly we would require intelligence to be measurable in order to be able to compare it. With certain definitions of intelligence measuring it is feasible. And lastly we would need to know her intelligence and the intelligence of the average person. But even if requirements one, two and three would be met the last requirement is probably not, for example if we assume intelligence to be a person's IQ, then we would have to know her IQ, which we assume we don't. So we can't agree or disagree with such a statement as we don't have enough knowledge.

How would you respond to such a question? Assume you want be authentic, i.e. you don't want to agree or disagree, you want to avoid a philosophical discussion about intelligence and you want to be polite and avoid an awkward situation or an abrupt ending of the conversation.

Side-question: What tags are suitable for such a question, i.e. what philosophical topics adhere to this kind of question?

Comment: "Thirdly we would require [assume] intelligence to be measurable in order to be able to compare it... we would have to know her IQ, which we assume [require] we don't". things don't have to be measurable, and IQ is arguably our best measure, to be compared. are you looking for other measures of intelligence? you could look into how multiple intelligence is scored. if you just want to compare your imaginary person to someone else, then, as speakpigeon says, almost anything goes

Comment: This is not a philosophical question, but a matter of social manners. There are many ways to respond to such an invite to compliment if you neither want to agree or disagree. E.g. instead make a compliment that is related. Like: "She certainly has this one well figured out" or "she solved that in no time". You can deflect by making a joke or asking about other feats. If pressed, you can say that you're not an expert. In this specific case, you could refer to multidimensional models of intelligence, saying that each person has their own skills and strengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post touches on several well-worn philosophical phenomena. I'll try to give an overview of them in the hopes it addresses your question, or failing that helps you decide what would. (In particular, I'll try as much to articulate these concerns as to answer them.) Wherever it seems I'm making sweeping or otherwise overly concise statements, that just reflects the further reading required to explore the phenomenon at hand.

You might alternatively be interested in how psychometrics reifies the quantification of psychological concepts (intelligence being the first historically), in which case this is technically the wrong SE, but I can suggest some reading material. But I'll assume hereafter the choice of the adjective *intelligent* isn't the main point of the question; you could just as easily be asking about personality traits.

> most people in fact have their own

The Platonic Socrates frequently undermined people's claim to know what a word meant by challenging them to define it, then providing apparent counterexamples to either necessity or sufficiency. Yet we still seem to know when to use specific descriptions, and in particular when to disagree with them and even call some such claims lies. In short, this is by understanding whole statements, questions etc. as emerging from words' interactions; one understands a term insofar as one understands such examples.

> if we assume intelligence to be a person's IQ, then we would have to know her IQ, which we assume we don't.

I don't know this person. My Bayesian prior for her IQ is the population's distribution of it. Well, I know people have commented on her intelligence, which gives me a Bayesian posterior. And if I knew *why* they said it, it would adjust again (in one direction if the reasons sounded especially forgiving, or in another if they didn't). So even if her IQ has never been measured, I have a kind of Bayesian knowledge, which with enough experience leads to a prior very tightly distributed around a high mean (if the evidence is suggestive of a high IQ, that is).

So far, I sound like a mathematician. A philosopher might object that intellectual dispositions are only so well-inferred in the light of past observations insofar as [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning) or something adjacent to it succeeds. In short, maybe she'll seem like an idiot tomorrow.

Speaking of dispositions, how well do we know a person's mental traits from their behaviours? That's a big topic in the philosophy of mind, with some even historically arguing the behaviours are [*all there are*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_behaviorism) to the mental traits.

> you want to avoid a philosophical discussion about intelligence and you want to be polite and avoid an awkward situation or an abrupt ending of the conversation.

In other words, how do you avoid voicing skeptical objections to the knowledge claim at hand? If you've familiarized yourself with answers to skepticism you find satisfactory (at least when you're not in philosophy mode), you'll have no such objections to voice. You probably don't struggle to politely hold your tongue when someone makes any old claim that assumes our senses aren't pure hallucination.

Comment: Good answer indeed, thank you! The only thing that is not compelling to me is how holding one‘s tongue would not result in awkwardness or the ending of the conversation?

Comment: @timtam If, though accepting some philosophical rescue of our common-sense assessments of people, you still want to suspend judgement on an individual, but you worry anything short of explicit agreement will create awkwardness or an awkward silence, that's a social issue I won't try to solve.

Comment: @JG I did not say that anything short of explicit agreement will create awkwardness,  I just said that keeping quiet will. In contrary I believe awkwardness can be avoided while still suspending judgement, that's the point of my question. But I have to agree that this is more of a social issue than a philosophical one.

Comment: @CriglCragl Since it's unimportant to my point, I've edited it out. I was only ever commenting on the standard deviation rather than the expectation, but [the data's mixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_differences_in_intelligence#Variability) so let's forget it.

Answer (score 1):

The example seems not like a request to assess intelligence, but just a social ritual of asking to confirm a compliment regardless of your actual opinion, as a courtesy.

Like when you are shown a baby photo and asked "isn't it cute?", you are expected to respond with "oh, so cute!", and not expected to say that the eyes are uneven and the nose too stubby for your taste.

A proper assessment of intelligence could **for many purposes** be done via an IQ-Test, since the IQ is reasonably well linked to diverse cognitive skills that are related to intelligence.

This might still not be satisfactory for less common situations, when a person might score average in IQ Tests but still seems to outperform age-peers in a challenge that seems related to intelligence (like having only a musical talent). In such cases it is appropriate to refer to the known weaknesses of IQ tests regarding to certain observable skill differences, and to state that sadly there is no available test to adequately assess that form of intelligence.

Otherwise said, a high score in an IQ test is always evidence of high mental skill in diverse meaningful areas, whereas a non-high score still allows for some exceptional mental skill in specific areas.

Answer (score 0):

I think intelligence is the ability to find solutions to problems. This is clearly not measurable. Different problems require different forms of intelligence. Einstein no doubt was very intelligent but by definition we have zero information about how well he would have performed in circumstances he never had to face. It is also likely that many intelligent people do not want to solve problems and opt instead to live a quiet life without ever giving a hint that they are more intelligent than other people. We only know of Einstein because he got the Nobel prize... It may be that many if not most people are more intelligent than they are motivated to demonstrate. Actually solving problems does not just require intelligence, it also requires motivation, which may be what most people really lack.

To answer the question, all we can do is make an assessment on the basis of people's actual performance, that is, what they actually do, and what they actually do can only be a very small sample of what they would be able to do in different circumstances.

The good news, so to speak, is that most people are probably more intelligent than they appears to be.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but instead of answering my question you just stated some thoughts about your own understanding of intelligence.

Comment: I don't think it's true that we only know of Einstein because he won a Nobel, especially since the discovery that won him a Nobel is not what he is most well known for.

Comment: @timtam You may not like my answer but I certainly answered. Essentially, all measure of intelligence is pie in the sky. All you can do is assess the intelligence demonstrated by the actual performance of some action. You cannot assess the intelligence of someone who hasn't done what he or she would be capable of doing in different circumstances. You don't know what I have in my pocket. Same thing.

Comment: @Sandejo Sure, same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I am sceptical of how general IQ is. See [IQ reliability vs validity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient#Validity_as_a_measure_of_intelligence) It was invented to pick up on remedial educational needs, and it's good for that. The Flynn effect, gradual change in population IQ, is likely linked to improving diets and more access to books and education.  IQ scores have been shown to be associated with such factors as nutrition, parental socioeconomic status, morbidity and mortality, perinatal environment, and motivation of test takers, linked to value placed on IQ in a given society. Tests are meant to provide estimates of 'q', a person's 'real' general or transferable intelligence.

I gave a detailed rundown of problems with IQ, especially poor reliability at the high end and very limited correlation between extreme IQ and creative or academic success, in this answer:
[Do IQ tests measure intelligence?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6764/do-iq-tests-measure-intelligence/85941#85941)

Good working memory, ability to visualise, being able to summarise or form insightful abstractions, and other mental skills that definitely  are transferable. I think possession of a good proportion of such skills is what we call in everyday language intelligence. I don't think it is much to do with comparisons, so much as scope types or range of problems a person can engage with.

Comment: By q, did you mean [g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_factor_(psychometrics))?

Comment: @J.G. Yes! Oops. Also, how are you doing hypertext links in comments?

Comment: AtextBCurlD where A=[ B=] C=( D=).

Comment: [Thank you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thank_You)